# Adding a new child to a real-time Firebase database using Vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

Template:

```
<div class="addPlant" v-else-if="addPlantShow">
  <div>
    <h5 class="goBack"@click="handleBackToCollection()">Back to {{selectedCollection.collectionName}}</h5>
    <h2>Add Plant to {{selectedCollection.collectionName}}</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="addPlant(selectedCollection)">
    <div>
      <label for="plantName">Name: </label>
      <input type="text" id="plantName" v-model="newPlant.plantName" required>
      <br>
      <label for="plantDescription">Description: </label>
      <input type="text" id="plantDescription" v-model="newPlant.plantDescription">
      <input type="submit" value="Add" @click="handleBackToCollection()">
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

selectedCollection is a specific collection I have clicked on in the browser.

Script:

```
import Firebase from 'firebase'
//firebase config here = {}
let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
let db = app.database();
let collectionsRef = db.ref('collections');

export default {
  firebase: {
    collections: collectionsRef
  },
  data() {
    return {
      newPlant : {
        plantDescription: "",
        plantName: "",
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addPlant(sc) {
      //How do I add a new child here if I don't know the specific branch?
      this.specificCollectionRef = sc.plants;
      collectionsRef.child(this.specificCollectionRef).push(this.newPlant);
      this.newPlant.plantDescription = "";
      this.newPlant.plantName = "";
  }
}
```

I only included plantDescription and plantName to simplify this a little more.

[image: JSON on Firebase:]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I push a new child when the child I want to push isn't explicit? The two lines of code in addPlant() are what I'm struggling with. Say I want to add a new plant to a specific collection that I have clicked on the page. I saved that clicked selected collection in an object but how I push that object (new plant) into that chosen collection? Maybe I'm just going about this all wrong.

Comment: If you have the correct value for the selected collection in `specificCollectionRef`, then it'd be `collectionsRef.child(this.specificCollectionRef).child("plants").push(this.newPlant);`

Comment: This helped a lot! Thank you! It wasn't the solution, but I was able to figure it out. The solution: `this.collectionRef = sc;`
 `collectionsRef.child(this.collectionRef['.key']).child("plants").push(this.newPlant);`

Comment: Great to hear Amy. Can you post that as an answer, so that others can more easily see how you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change the first two lines of code in newPlant() to:

```
this.collectionRef = sc;
collectionsRef.child(this.collectionRef['.key']).child("plants").push(this.newPlant);
```